# Getting python argparse to use only part of the default value in certain cases

Tags: python, argparse

Is there any easy way I can get this to return the respective default value if a non-int or non-float value were to be provided as an argument to the script when called from the console/shell?

```
import argparse

def check(v):
    try:
        return float(v)
    except:
        #return default value for respective index in default list

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('-data',dest='data', type = check, nargs=5,
                    default=[-1,1,-7.9,512,0])
data = args.data
print(data)
```

For example if the following args are provided:

```
file.py -data 1 6.03 1 p 1
```

I would want just the `p` to be replaced, so `data` would print `[1, 6.03, 1, 512, 1]`. Thanks.

Comment: Problem is that `check` only gets the current string, not its position in the nargs 5.  Have you tried writing a function to do this replacement after parsing?  That would be the simplest place to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can raise a `ValueError` on `type` check, then get all arguments with `sys.argv`, grab the index of the arg with the non-float/non-int value and replace with the default value at that index. `defaults` is a dict with the default values in a list.

```
import argparse
import sys

def check(v):
    try:
        value = float(v)
        return value
    except ValueError:     #raise ValueError if the arg is not int           
        defaults = vars(parser.parse_args([]))   #get all the default values as a dict
        args = sys.argv[2:]         #exclude args at 0 and 1 index
        v_index = args.index(v)     #grab index at v              
        v = defaults['data'][v_index]  #assign the default value at v's index to 'v'
        return v

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-data', dest='data',type = check, nargs=5, default=[-1,1,-7.9,512,0]) 
args = parser.parse_args() 
print(args.data)
```

Lets test this now with the arguments you provided. My file is called test.py:

```
python test.py -data 1 6.03 1 p 1
#Output:
[1.0, 6.03, 1.0, 512, 1.0]
```

Lets add another non-int/non-float arg to the mix:

```
python test.py -data 1 6.03 x p 1
#Output:
[1.0, 6.03, -7.9, 512, 1.0]
```

**Edit**: The following is a generalized solution, independent of the flag provided('-data', '-name'):

```
def check(v):
    #<--same-->
    except ValueError:             
        defaults = vars(parser.parse_args([]))   
        args = sys.argv[2:]                 
        arg_spec = str(sys.argv[1][1:]) #get the flag specified, '-name' etc.        
        v_index = args.index(v)     #grab index at v              
        v = defaults[arg_spec][v_index]  #assign the default value at v's index to 'v'
        return v

#add another flag to the arguments, 
#identify the flag passed with sys.argv, 
#convert the args passed into a dict,
#select the flag key to get its value(the args for the flag) from the dict

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-data', dest='data',type = check, nargs=5, default=[-1,1,-7.9,512,0]) 
parser.add_argument('-name', dest='name',type = check, nargs=5, default=[5,20,606,81,15])
args = parser.parse_args() 
arg_spec = sys.argv[1][1:]
args_dict = vars(args)
print("The flag you provided is: '{}'. The args are: {}".format(sys.argv[1], args_dict[arg_spec]))
```

Some tests:

```
python test.py -name 1 6.03 1 x 1
#Output:
The flag you provided is: '-name'. The args are: [1.0, 6.03, 1.0, 81, 1.0]

python test.py -data 1 6.03 1 x 1
#Output:
The flag you provided is: '-data'. The args are: [1.0, 6.03, 1.0, 512, 1.0]
```

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot. One more question. I have 3 more optional argument sets (lets just say -color, -shape, -name) that I would also like to use check(v) for. Without making 4 check(v) functions, how can I replace v = defaults['data'][v_index] so that it uses 'data' 'color' 'shape' 'name'? Seems like I can only feed in one argument to check(v) in order to use it as type.

Comment: If you are looking to do the same _type-check-replace-default value_ routine, then you don't need separate `check(v)` functions. Just use the same for each argument. If this answer was helpful, please upvote/accept as answer.

Comment: I'm a tad confused what you mean by the same for each argument. Also maybe using argparse won't be able to really solve my problem now that I look at it more. As an example I would need -data 1 1 1 1 y -name t 1 1 to change both the y and the t to their respective default values (etc) and I'm not sure how I would be able to find the index just in terms of being after -name/any optional arguments after the first optional argument.

Comment: For name, just use the 'name' key to get default values: v = defaults['name'][v_index]. I'll update my answer soon, that will take care of all args.

Comment: I believe I understand that, just not entirely sure how I can recognize/differentiate which default key to use. Additionally, for the -name t 1 1 example, I would need the indexing to start over again with -name otherwise I don't think I can get the correct default index assuming I want to be able to use any number of my four optional arguments in any order.

Comment: I've added a generalized solution to this problem. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to split your argument of 5 into 5 different arguments, --data1 --data2 (or even give better more descriptive names for each data point) because now it is positional so it is hard to gauge which argument is not filled in.
You could also like you did in your example pass a dummy value like your 'p' and then when you parse your args you could replace those with your preset defaults.

`my_data = [default[i] if x == 'p' else x for i, x in enumerate(data)]`